# how to re-use a profile in Selenium instead of copy a new profile

Tags: selenium, cookies, authentication

I have a website to auto login. If login manually, the cookie will be stored 3 days, and 3 days' later I have to manually login again. Then I used Selenium to do auto login, the Selenium app could re-start many times a day. After manually login using the profile, the Selenium app doesn't need to login since it's already login, after 3 days, Selenium needs to run auto login, but I hope in the next 3 days, it don't need to login again as I expected the new cookie should be stored in the profile files. But in reality, it does auto login every time and the reason might be Selenium COPY the profile to a new place and use that folder as profile. How to make Selenium use an existing folder as profile, instead of every time copy the existing folder to a new place

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried by creating the firefox profile and calling that profile by name?

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium");
WebDriver driver = FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Please create firefox profile from profile manager, then name it, may be selenium and do all your work like login, saving password etc. Call this named profile as per above script.

[Here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) is the steps to create firefox profile

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: yes, I did that but in clojure. But it doesn't work. After login in, it should create some cookies about login so that next time access it won't need to login again. however it still need login in. I guess selenium doesn't use the profile folder created by "profile manager", instead it copies that folder to a new place, and use that new folder for later operation, after close selenium that new folder is gone, if start selenium again, it will re-copy so the login info doesn't saved cross different execution

Comment: When finished (atexit, abort, or whatever), copy back the contents of the folder at `profile._path_`, which is the real path used in that selenium execution.